# i have a problem in pycharm 3 with a list and an equation

Tags: python, list, pycharm

I have a list of materials with values and an equation `R=(wt/material)`. I'm not to sure how to have an input of a material example copper and it takes the value copper from the list and applies it to the equation

```
material = [229.11, 386.12, 112.81, 59.31, 136.07, 69.78, 66.04, 172.12, 50.24, 93.04, 36.87, 70.01, 410.54, 45.36]
aluminijum, bakar, cink, gvozdje, kalijum, kobalt, kalaj, magnezijum, mangan, nikl, olovo, platina, srebro, celik = material

print('racun za ravan zid')

wall_thickness = float(input('debljina zida:'))
input("material:")****
R = wall_thickness / material

T_1 = float(input('temperatura_1:'))

T_2 = float(input('temperatura_2:'))
    
q = (T_1 - T_2) / R
```

I've tried the input function but its says that it cant convert strings to float

Comment: Would you mind formatting your question and code properly? As it stands, there are a couple of indention errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `float()` function and then between brackets the `input()` function. It will try to convert the given input to the `float` type. If the input value could not be converted to  `float` it will throw a **ValueError**

```
material = float(input())
```

Comment: i tried that too but it still says that it cant convert str to float i guess i need to add a for function that reads the list first then when it finds the material it can apply it to the equation but i dont know how to do that but thank you for the answer

Comment: what doy ou try to input? @pcprincipal

Comment: @pcprincipal write me the exact thing that you enter please

Comment: ill make it shorter i have a list material=[229.11] then i name the value aluminum = material and the equation says that R = the wall thickness / material , then i wrote wall_thickness = float(input('wall_thickness:')) and then i tried the same with the material , material = float(input('material:')) and when i run this it says error i cant conver str to float for the material but the wall thickness one works sorry if im not to clear im new to this

Comment: @pcprincipal are you sure? I tried the exact same commands and they are working.

Comment: @pcprincipal are you sure that the value you input can be converted to the `float`? the `float` is for example `5.25` important note there, is that it has `.` instead of `,`

Comment: yeahh i guess beacuse i have a list of values it reads all of them then when i input some material it gets stuck im using pycharm comunity 2019 3.3 btw

Comment: @pcprincipal I do not understand. You tell me that you have a list and then you want to erase it and make an input out of it. please write once again what you want to achieve

Comment: when i run the code i want it to ask me what material do you want and when i type lets say copper it calculates R = wall thickenss / copper or if i type iron it calculates for the value of iron if that makes sense

Comment: @pcprincipal copper is a word. It means that it is a `string` the `float` is a number. How do you want to take a numeral value from a word?

Comment: beacuse when i made the list for every value i gave it a certain material like 229.11 is for iron 386.12 is copper...

Comment: @pcprincipal you have to use dictionairy. your code should look like that `materials = {'copper' : 5.2} m = input()` and then `R = the wall thickness / materials[m]`

Comment: @pcprincipal can you upvote and accept my answer please?